# List only CPT posts that have ACF date field set to yesterdays date

Tags: wordpress

Please advise. I have CPT with one ACF date field and I have to list only CPT posts that have that ACF date field set to yesterdays date or set to any other date before yesterday. I am using Oxygen Builder with WordPress and I manage to find some code for dynamic queries with oxygen repeter and this is the code but since i don't know PHP i can't get it to work:

```
<?php
function dynamic_query_hraci( $query ) {

  if ( $query->query['post_type'][0] == 'CPT_slug' ) {
     $today = date("Y-m-d");
    
    
    
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
          array(
                'key' => 'ACF_date_field',
                'value' => $today,
                'compare' => '<',
        )));     
    
    $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true );
  }
}
 
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'dynamic_query_hraci' );
?>
```

I made sure that all dates are saved in the same format Y-m-d. Am i going in the right direction with this code?

Comment: how did you check in DB how dates are stored?

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, i am new in stackoverflow. I didn't checked the value in DB because i can't find that in phpmyadmin but i made sure from the wordpress that all dates has same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Ymd`. as per their documentation The date format is returned when loading the value. Please note that the value is always saved as Ymd (YYYYMMDD) in the database. check here for more info https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/date-picker/

```
<?php
    function dynamic_query_hraci( $query ) {

        if ( $query->query['post_type'][0] == 'CPT_slug' ) {

            $today = date("Ymd");
        
            $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
                array(
                    'key'     => 'ACF_date_field',
                    'value'   => $today,
                    'compare' => '<',
                )
            ));     
        
            $query->set( 'no_found_rows', true );
        }

    }
    add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'dynamic_query_hraci' );
?>
```